# Textarea content to td while retaining carriage returns

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a textarea that gets put into a DB on submission and then pulled into a td element elsewhere.

Pulling it back into a textarea it keep the original formatting. However it should go into a td but that ignores the carriage returns.

How can I get the content from a textarea into a td or perhaps another HTML element other than a form and retain at least the carriage returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at the [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap` style properties to the `<td>`